# How to iterate over a list of type Class to edit the properties of its objects in Groovy

Tags: loops, grails, groovy, closures, each

I know there are more elaborate ways to achieve this in Java, but Groovy should have a concise way to do the same as per http://groovy.codehaus.org/Looping

**Class Currency.groovy**

```
class Currency {
    String name
    double rate
}
```

**CurrencyController**

```
def select(){
    List<Currency> selectedCurrencies = Currency.getAll(params.currencies)
    selectedCurrencies.eachWithIndex { obj, i -> obj.rate = update(obj.name)};
    [selectedCurrencies:selectedCurrencies]
}

def update(String sym){
    return sym
}
```

**The above code throws:**

```
No signature of method: currencychecker.CurrencyController$_$tt__select_closure12.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (currencychecker.Currency)
```

Comment: You can just use `each` method.

Comment: `obj[i]` does not make sense. `obj` already is the iterated element of `selectedCurrencies`.

Comment: @Opal each also doesn't work! it throws a "No signature of method: currencychecker.CurrencyController$_$tt__select_closure12.doCall() is applicable for argument types" is the syntax correct?

Comment: @dmahapatro correct, fixed that! although still similar error! is the rest correct?

Comment: @SabaAhang: in `each` there's only a single argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dmahapatro, the issue was that I was using an iterator variable `obj[i]`, even though `obj` itself is the iterated object. The rest is correct!
I experimented with `selectCurrencies.each` as well instead of `selectCurrencies.eachWithIndex` however the right one in this case is `eachWithIndex`

Comment: As Opal mentioned earlier `.each` should work as well. I am not sure what kind of problem that is being faced with `each` but both each and eachWithIndex are similar with the only difference that with the later one you get the corresponding `index` to play around.

Comment: right! `each` should be used with `{ obj ->`  and `eachWithIndex` should be used with `{ obj, i ->`